# initialization of static std::initializer_list causes VS2015 Update 3 warning C4592

Tags: c++, stdinitializerlist

I need static std::initializer_list to parametrize my gtest template fixture. So for any tested type I need to initialize fixture member, like below (last line):

```
template <typename T>
class ExampleTemplatedUnitTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected: 
    static std::initializer_list<typename T::value_type> initializers;
};
TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(ExampleTemplatedUnitTest);

TYPED_TEST_P(ExampleTemplatedUnitTest, exampleTest) {
    for (auto p : ExampleTemplatedUnitTest<TypeParam>::initializers)
        printf("p = %d", p);
}
REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(ExampleTemplatedUnitTest, exampleTest);
typedef ::testing::Types<
    std::vector<int>
> testedTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(value, ExampleTemplatedUnitTest, testedTypes);

std::initializer_list<int> ExampleTemplatedUnitTest<std::vector<int>>::initializers = { 1,2 };
```

However it fires following warning:

```
unit_test.cpp(502): warning C4592: 'initializers': symbol will be dynamically initialized (implementation limitation)
```

I've found this question:
[error C4592: symbol will be dynamically initialized. VS2015.1 static const std::vector field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013930/error-c4592-symbol-will-be-dynamically-initialized-vs2015-1-static-const-std)
and lot of other topics, but all concerns a bug in Update 1.

Thus I still can't understand what I do wrong? Shall I ignore and disable this warning or there is a way I can fix it? Test passes and behave exactly like I want. (In real-life tests I use this static init list to actually initialize objects with constructors with std::initializer_list, above code is just shortened example)

I've used this parametrization of typed test technique for long time and haven't encountered this, but it is first time with std::initializer_list

Comment: Are you compiling against C++14 or C++17?

Comment: I believe the error says it all. It in an "implementation limitation," meaning that in the version you are using, the compiler cannot handle it properly. In VS2019 16.3, this works fine without warnings.

Comment: A workaround for this is to store the parameters in a `std::tuple` and then you can unpack the tuple into the constructor calls.

Comment: @NathanOliver I use default C++ version for VS2015 Update 3 (I would consider it as C++11). I don't understand this workaround - shall I construct initializer_list from tuple somehow?

Comment: @ChrisMM but is it ok to ignore this warning if I don't rely on static initialization in this case?

Comment: Yes; my understanding is that it will just initialize it at run time, instead of at compile time. Other than a very slight performance penalty, should be okay.